# ¿Como generar números aleatorios dentro de un rango de valores?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber como generar un numero al azar (Random) dando un intervalo de valores.

Por ejemplo, con el intervalo 1 a 10, quiero obtener
`4,6,3,9,10,3,1,5,2,...` pero nunca `0,-1,11,12..`

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Saludos

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681/1983854

Answer (score 24):

```
numero = (int) (Math.random() * n) + 1;
```

Donde `n` es hasta el número que quieres que llegue, `+ 1` para que nunca tengas un `0` y el cast a `int` porque `Math#random` arroja un valor de tipo `double`.

Answer (score 15):

En *Java* existen dos clases principales para generar números aleatorios:

- `java.util.Random`
- `java.security.SecureRandom`

La función `Math.random()` usa `java.util.Random` por si acaso.

Mientras tanto, no es de gran importancia si los datos producidos son realmente aleatorios, `Math.random()` o `Random` hagan el trabajo, pero hay un problema:

Si genero datos aleatorios con la misma secuencia de código y con la misma semilla, siempre se van a generar los mismos datos que parecen aleatorios, pero en realidad son reproducibles. Por la misma razón, típicamente se usa un **sello de tiempo** (como `System.currentTimeMillis()`) para generar nuevos datos.

En la práctica se usa el código:

```
Random aleatorio = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
// Producir nuevo int aleatorio entre 0 y 99
int intAletorio = aleatorio.nextInt(100);
// Más código

// Refrescar datos aleatorios 
aleatorio.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
// ... o mejor
aleatorio.setSeed(aleatorio.getLong());
```

**¿Qué hago en el caso que quiero asegurarme que genero realmente datos aleatorios?**

Si necesito más seguridad que mis datos aleatorios no sean reproducibles, por ejemplo en criptografía u otras áreas de seguridad, debería usar otra forma de generar datos aleatorios.

La criptografía provee para estos usos los **PRNG** (*pseudorandom number generator*), generadores de números pseudoaleatorios. ¿Por qué pseudo? Bueno, en realidad un sistema informático convencional es incapaz de fácilmente hacer algo aleatorio, es demasiado determinístico para eso. Pero existen algoritmos que proveen una aproximación suficientemente aleatorio para cumplir con todas las tareas que los necesita.

La clase `SecureRandom` trabaja con algoritmos como el *SHA1PRNG* de *Sun*, que cumplen con los requerimientos del [*RFC 1750* (en inglés)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1750.txt) sobre generación de datos aleatorios criptográficamente fuerte (no determinístico).

En la generación de identificadores de sesiones, por ejemplo, es altamente recomendable de preferir `SecureRandom` sobre `Random`.

¿Cómo se usa?

En primer lugar tengo que decidir si prefiero dejar la selección del mejor algoritmo a la plataforma o si necesito definirlo para garantizar el mismo algoritmo en todas instalaciones.

```
// Generar un nuevo generador con el algoritmo por defecto
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
```

o

```
SecureRandom sr = null;
try {
    sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
    // para garantizar el caracter aleatorio generemos una nueva semilla
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Luego hay que iniciar el generador, que se hace solicitando bytes aleatorios.

```
// La lista byte[] es suficiente, la llamada se hace únicamente para causar la generación de una nueva semilla 
sr.nextBytes(new byte[1]);
```

El generador está listo para usar, y puedo generar números aleatorios en una variedad de formas. Algunas tienen ambas clases en común:

```
// Un valor long
sr.nextLong();
// Un valor int
sr.nextInt();
// Un valor float
sr.nextFloat();
// Un valor double
sr.nextDouble();
// Un valor gaussian (entre -1 y 1))
sr.nextGaussian();
// Un valor boolean, como lanzar una moneda
sr.nextBoolean();
// ... y un valor int entre 0 (inclusivo) y int n (exclusivo)
sr.nextInt(n);
// Así para tener un valor entero aleatorio de 1 al 10, se usa
sr.nextInt(10)+1;
```

Además, `SecureRandom` ofrece más métodos:

```
// Un valor int de int x bits, ajustado a la derecha
sr.next(x);
// Para obtener una cantidad de bytes aleatorios, se `puede usar lo siguiente
byte[] b = new byte[128]
sr.getBytes(b);
```

Para mejorar el carácter aleatorio se debe sembrar el generador cada vez en tanto:

```
byte[] b = new byte[20];
sr.setSeed(b)
// Alternativamente se puede usar un long para resembrar
sr.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Resembrar nunca baja la aleatoriedad del generador, porque la nueva semilla complementa la semilla que se usó inicialmente.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes usar la clase `ThreadLocalRandom` que hace exáctamente lo que necesitas.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

int numero = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

Comment: Sería mejor utilizar [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) que es padre de esta clase y trabaja bien en ambientes locales como un método.

Comment: creo que es innecesario preocupar al OP con concurrencia e hilos cuando hablamos de algo tan basico

Comment: @JordiCastilla en realidad nunca se sabe, puede que la instancia si se utilice en múltiples hilos.

Comment: La razón por la que preferí este método en lugar de la clase `Random` es porque explícitamente te deja indicar el mínimo y máximo, no necesita ninguna manipulación extra (además del `+ 1` en max) o recordar una fórmula.  @LuiggiMendoza existe alguna desventaja de utilizarla?

Comment: No he trabajado con `ThreadLocalRandom` pero según veo en sus fuentes la diferencia entre su `nextInt` y el de `Random` es que en `Random` tiene una semilla por instancia mientras que `ThreadLocalRandom` tiene una semilla por hilo donde se ejecuta. La verdad no haría mucha diferencia.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //hay que importar la librerai Random
    //java.util.Random

    //generador de numeros aleatorios
    Random generadorAleatorios = new Random();

    //genera un numero entre 1 y 5 y lo guarda en la variable numeroAleatorio
    int numeroAleatorio = 1+generadorAleatorios.nextInt(5);
    //imprimo el numero en consola
    System.out.println(numeroAleatorio);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una buena forma de generar intervalos seria la siguiente:

```
Random aleatorio = new Random();
System.out.println(8+aleatorio.nextInt( (10+1) - 8));
```

De esta manera los numeros se generaran en un rango del 8 al 10.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede utilizar el método `nextInt(bound)` de `java.util.Random`.
Este método genera un número aleatorio dentro del *intervalo abierto* entre `0` inclusivo y el número pasado al método `nextInt(bound)` exclusivo.

Por lo tanto, para resolver el problema se deberá llamar a `nextInt` pasándole como parámetro la resta entre el *límite superior* provisto `+ 1` menos el *límite inferior*. Posteriormente se le suma el *límite inferior*. El código quedaría:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

`...`

```
int limiteInferior = 1;
int limiteSuperior = 10;
int limiteSuperiorAbierto = limiteSuperior + 1;
int numeroAleatorio = limiteInferior + random.nextInt(limiteSuperiorAbierto - limiteInferior);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo un tutorial muy completo y facil de entender sobre los `Math.random` y los `random.nextInt`:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-java-between-range.html

para tu caso en especial, el codigo seria:

```
for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
    int randomInteger = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
    System.out.println("pseudo random int in a range : " + randomInteger);
}

Output:
pseudo random int in a range : 7
pseudo random int in a range : 1
pseudo random int in a range : 3
```

Comment: `random#nextInt(10)` genera un número entre 0 y 9, no entre 1 y 10...

Comment: Lo se, era un copy+paste del ejemplo...

Comment: Entonces lo tuyo no es una respuesta, sino un copiado/pegado de un sitio X.

Comment: @M.Mariscal sumale uno hombre, que no te cuesta nada!

Comment: Se me olvido cambiarlo, fallo HUMANO, eso de restar por el fallo de olvidarse algo es PATETICO...

Comment: No es el fallo HUMANO, sino la falta de sentido por apoyar a otros HUMANOS con la respuesta. Cualquier HUMANO puede copiar/pegar texto aleatorio asociado a una pregunta. Incluso un HUMANO puede crear una aplicación para que una COMPUTADORA pueda hacer eso en lugar de él/ella. No cualquier HUMANO puede brindar una respuesta.

Comment: Respuesta actualizada...

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo donde definimos valores entre un rango de valores min y max :

```
int numeroRandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max);
```

podemos realizar lo mismo mediante un metodo:

```
private int getNumeroRandom(int min, int max){
       return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max);
   }
```

un ejemplo de como llamar el metodo para obtener un numero aleatorio en un rango de 1 a 10:

```
int min = 1, max = 10;
System.out.println(getNumeroRandom(min, max));
```

Este es un ejemplo de 100 iteraciones obtenidas con el metodo sugerido, definiendo como intervalo  1 al 10:

```
8, 9, 2, 1, 2, 4, 9, 4, 1, 4, 7, 2, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 8, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 8, 5, 7, 5, 8, 5, 1, 6, 7, 2, 2, 6, 7, 1, 7, 4, 8, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 8, 5, 4, 9, 4, 7, 5, 4, 8, 3, 7, 8, 4, 4, 1, 7, 4, 8, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 8, 9, 4, 9, 9, 9, 4, 5, 9, 6
```