# ¿Cómo crear un "selector aleatorio" (Random) en Android?

Tags: android, random, generator

Ante todo, espero que sea clara mi duda:

Estoy creando un juego simple de trivial. se muestra una pregunta al jugador, con las cuatro respuestas posibles (sólo una es correcta). Si el usuario acierta, **pasa a otra pregunta elegida al azar**.

Así tengo las preguntas:

```
   public void pregunta1(){

      textView.setText("¿Cómo te llamas?");

      textViewOpcion1.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener){...
      //esta es la opción correcta. pasa a otra pregunta:
       preguntaAleatoria();
      }

      textViewOpcion2
      textViewOpcion3
      textViewOpcion4
   }
```

Otra pregunta:

```
   public void pregunta2(){

      textView.setText("¿Quién se comió mi bocadillo?");

      textViewOpcion1
      textViewOpcion2

      textViewOpcion3.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener){...
      //esta es la opción correcta.
       preguntaAleatoria();
      }

      textViewOpcion4
   }
```

Muchas más preguntas:

```
     public void pregunta3(){...}


     public void pregunta4(){...}


     public void pregunta5(){...}

    ...
```

Insisto. **preguntaAleatoria();** debe llamar a cualquiera de las preguntas **(pregunta1(); , pregunta2(); , pregunta3(); , pregunta4(); o pregunta5();)** Sin repetir la misma, salvo hayan pasado todas!!!

Comment: Y... ¿por qué un método para cada pregunta? ¿No sería mejor tenerlas todas en un array e ir mostrándolas de forma aleatoria? Ejemplo: `String[] array = array; String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];` Esto te puede servir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600001/how-to-get-a-random-value-from-a-string-array-in-android

Comment: uso métodos porque en cada pregunta correcta se ejecutan varias "acciones". por ejemplo, se ganan puntos, se llama a un temporizador (countDownTimer), etc. sin los métodos no sabria cómo ejecutar todo eso.

Comment: Eso no es problema, el array lo creas tú y pones no sólo las preguntas, sino un identificador y ... más cosas que necesites. Luego pasas a tu método lo que se haya seleccionado y también lo que queda en el array, o sea las preguntas aún no planteadas. En el método evalúas... si se eligió el identificador 1 del array haz esto, si el 2 haz lo otro... un típico `switch ... case...`o un simple `if then else...` y si hay que seguir preguntando... como tienes lo que queda del array en parámetro haces otra pregunta random. Espero haberme explicado. Saludos.

Comment: Esto podría servir para tu propósito: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11972962/5587982

Answer (score 1):

No creo que sea óptimo hacer un método por cada pregunta. puedes guardarlas en un arreglo de dos dimensiones donde guardes la pregunta y sus posibles respuestas (y si le entiendes a lo de los arreglos de varias dimensiones puedes guardar el numero de la respuesta correcta en el principio de el arreglo de respuestas).Si no entiendes lo de la respuesta, puedes crear otro arreglo con los indices de las respuestas correctas de cada pregunta.

Crea una clase que se llame pregunta y que contenga un arraylist de preguntas y después genera los metodos necesarios para mantener esa estrcutura.

Para lo de escogerlas aleatoriamente puedes usar la clase Ramdom de Java, y usar una semilla que cambie para que no se repita cada vez que incies el juego.

Algo como esto.

```
public class Pregunta {
    public static ArrayList <ArrayList <String>> preguntas= new ArrayList <>();

   //crea los metodos para mantener la estructura
   public void agregarPregunta(String pregunta,String a, String b,String c, String d){

        // en la primera posicion pones la pregunta
        preguntas.get(preguntas.size()).add(pregunta);
       // en la segunda posicion pones la respuesta correcta
       preguntas.get(preguntas.size()).add(a);
       //despues agregas todos los demas respuestas incorrectas
       preguntas.get(preguntas.size()).add(b);
       preguntas.get(preguntas.size()).add(c);
       preguntas.get(preguntas.size()).add(d);
   }
}
```

En tu mainActivity, solo instancias a esa clase y usas su arraylist para ir iterando en las preguntas e ir poniendolas en el UI, pra poner las respuestas en orden aleatorio usa ramdom.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46062/31409

de ahí lo puedes sacar, cuidado con los indices no te vayas a salir del tamaño del array,list.

despues con tu clickonlistener pregunta solamente si la opcion que escogio el participante es igual a la segunda posicion del arraylist, si es asi esta correcta.

Saludos.

Comment: La idea es clara. El problema estará en que practicamente nunca trabajé con `ArrayList()` . Entiendo el código. pero encuentro dos problemas. No veo donde llamar al `OnClickListener`. lo otro es que no sé crear un `Random`. no sé mucho de java. por eso intentaba buscar atajos con los métodos. jj

Comment: buscar atajos no justifica que hagas esa aberración de código, no te preocupes vamos aprendiendo en el camino.  el onclickListener lo vas a llamar en tu mainActivity, dependiendo de como quieras que funcione la app, debes separar la lógica del programa de la UI, entonces pues haz una sola actividad que vaya iterando el arraylist de preguntas y y recicla es la idea de mi código. y lo del random, revisa el enlace que te mande , es muy claro lo que dice el autor.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente conseguí lo que necetitaba, sin modificar la estructura de mis preguntas.

Añadiendo las lineas:

```
private static final Random generador = new Random();
private static final Integer[] preguntas = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};



public void nuevaPregunta(){

    int pregunta = preguntas[generador.nextInt(preguntas.length)];
    String p = String.valueOf(pregunta);
```

Al llamar al método `nuevaPregunta();` me devuelve un número al azar. Paso el numero recibido a `Sreing`, y finalmente establezco condiciones. Si el nñumero es 2, se obtiene la pregunta2... Y así obtengo las preguntas aleatoriamente:

```
    if (p.equals("2")){
        pregunta2();
    }
```

Cuando la respuesta es correcta:

```
   textViewOpcion3.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener){...
  //esta es la opción correcta. Se llama a una nueva pregunta
   NuevaPregunta();
  }
```