# ¿Como se puede generar caracteres aleatorios con Math.random?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando generar matrículas de coches aleatorias que se autogeneren en el constructor de una clase coche.
Las matrículas están compuestas por 4  dígitos y 3 letras. Por ejemplo: 0001JFK, 2245HRY etc.

De qué manera puedo generar letras de manera aleatoria y  completar con ceros el numero de la matricula si no es de 4 cifras?

Este es el código que tengo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            matricula=(int) (Math.random()*9999+1); 
            System.out.print(matricula+"  ");
        }
```

Comment: Hola David. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Para las letras forma un array con las posibles letras en matriculas, y saca aleatroriamente 3. Para los ceros, pon delante tantos ceros como `4 - numero0-9999.length`

Comment: Lo queme dijiste de los ceros no te entendí peroestuve mirando esto:                                                                                                        String mystring="123";
 String matri = String.format("%010d", Integer.parseInt(mystring));    System.out.println(matri);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para generar valores aleatorios en **Java** existe una clase llamada `Random` en el paquete `java.util.Random`. Esta clase posee métodos que te permiten obtener números pseudo-aleatorios.

Para resolver tu problema usaremos la tabla de caracteres [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) y el método `nextInt()` de la clase `Random`  para generar valores enteros entre 0 y 9 para obtener los dígitos, y también entre 65 y 90 para obtener las letras a partir de la conversión de números enteros a caracteres de la tabla [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Para que podamos utilizar la clase `Random` tenemos que importar primero el paquete `java.util.Random` al comienzo del nuestro archivo fuente. Esta es la manera de importarlo:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Luego podrás implementar esta parte código para almacenar como cadena de texto tu matrícula con valores aleatorios:

```
// Inicializamos la variable que almacenará la matrícula.
String Matricula = "";
// Inicializamos la instancia de la clase Random con la que
// generaremos el valor aleatorio.
Random rnd = new Random();

// Creamos un ciclo que se ejecute 7 veces, que corresponden al
// texto de la matrícula.
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    // Con este condicional verificamos si estamos en la parte
    // numérica o alfabética de la matrícula.
    // Solo debe entrar al condicional si estamos generando los
    // números de la matrícula.
    if(i < 4)
    {
        // Con esta instrucción se genera un número aleatorio entre
        // 0 y 9, no se incluye el 10.
        Matricula += rnd.nextInt(10);
    }
    // Entrará en esta parte del condicional cuando estemos generando
    // las letras de la matrícula.
    else
    {
        // Con esta instrucción se genera un número aleatorio entre
        // 65 y 90, no se incluye el 91. Luego se convierte a un 
        // caracter ASCII.
        Matricula += (char)(rndnextInt(91) + 65);
    }
}

// Por último imprimimos la matrícula en la consola.
System.out.println("La matrícula es: " + Matricula);
```

> De manera en que así te quedaría el código que propongo para tu problema:
>
> ```
> ...
> import java.util.Random;
>
> public static void main(String[] args) 
> {
>     String Matricula = "";
>     Random rnd = new Random();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
>     {
>         if(i < 4)
>         {
>             Matricula += rnd.nextInt(10);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             Matricula += (char)(rndnextInt(91) + 65);
>         }
>     }
>
>     System.out.println("La matrícula es: " + Matricula);
> }
> ```

Si desearas que la parte alfabética de la matrícula generada aleatoriamente  no contenga una serie de caracteres puedes usar el método `indexOf()` de la clase `String` en conjunto con un bucle `while` para comparar si el carácter generado se encuentra en la lista de letras que no deseas que aparezcan en tu matrícula y así no imprimirlo.

> Para lograr eso, en conjunto con el método `Random.nextInt()`, te propongo el siguiente código:
>
> ```
> ...
> import java.util.Random;
>
> public static void main(String[] args) 
> {
>     char Caracter;
>     String Matricula = "";
>    // Aquí se definen las letras que no quieres que se generen.
>     String CaracteresNoDeseados = "AEIOU";
>     Random rnd = new Random();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
>     {
>         if(i < 4)
>         {
>             Matricula += rnd.nextInt(10);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>                 do 
>             {
>                 Caracter = (char)(rndnextInt(91) + 65);
>             // Si el carácter existe en la cadena de texto 
>             // de los no deseados, se repite el bucle
>             } while (CaracteresNoDeseados.indexOf(Character) >= 0)
>
>             Matricula += Caracter;
>         }
>     }
>
>     System.out.println("La matrícula es: " + Matricula);
> }
> ```

En esta [guía](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Generar_n%C3%BAmeros_aleatorios_en_Java) que habla acerca de cómo generar números aleatorios con la clase `Random`. Encontrarás también que puedes generar un número aleatorio con la clase `Math` y su método `random` en esta [página](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/numero-aleatorio-en-java/). Usar el método `Math.random` es válido también, así que podrías también intentar aplicarlo para tu solución.

> Si deseas cambiar el uso del método  `Random.nextInt()` por el método
>   `Math.random()` debes eliminar la línea en donde se declara la
>   variable `rnd`  y cambiar las siguientes líneas de código:
>
> ```
> Matricula += rnd.nextInt(10);
> ```
>
> **Por:**
>
> ```
> Matricula += (int) Math.floor(Math.round() * 10);
> ```
>
> *Y*
>
> ```
> Matricula += (char)(rndnextInt(91) + 65);
> ```
>
> **Por:**
>
> ```
> Matrícula += (char)((int) Math.floor(Math.round() * 91 + 65));
> ```

Para más información acerca de la creación de valores aleatorios mira la siguiente [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46062/84296):

> En Java existen dos clases principales para generar números
>   aleatorios:
>
> java.util.Random
>
> java.security.SecureRandom
>
> La función Math.random() usa java.util.Random por si acaso.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, te voy a puntuar la respuesta como muy buena. Ahora toca intentar quitar las vocales  matriculas. imagino que con do_while mientras el codigo ascii de las  vocales no sea igual al de las vocales.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido hacerlo de esta forma:

```
    private String generarMatricula() {
    matricula = "";
    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (i < 4) {    // 0,1,2,3 posiciones de numeros
            matricula = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + "" + matricula;

        } else {       // 4,5,6 posiciones de letras
            do {
                a = (int) (Math.random() * 26 + 65);///
            } while (a == 65 || a == 69 || a == 73 || a == 79 || a == 85);

            char letra = (char) a;
            if (i == 4) {
                matricula = matricula + "-" + letra;
            } else {
                matricula = matricula + "" + letra;
            }

        }
    }
    return matricula;
}
```

Pero voy a probar con indexOf para quitar las vocales.

```
    private String generarMatricula() {
    matricula = "";
    int a;
     String CaracteresNoDeseados = "AEIOU";
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (i < 4) {    // 0,1,2,3 posiciones de numeros
            matricula = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + "" + matricula;

        } else {       // 4,5,6 posiciones de letras
            do {
                a = (int) (Math.random() * 26 + 65);///
            } while (CaracteresNoDeseados.indexOf(a) >= 0);

            char letra = (char) a;
            if (i == 4) {
                matricula = matricula + "-" + letra;
            } else {
                matricula = matricula + "" + letra;
            }

        }
    }
    return matricula;
```

Ambas formas funcionan bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por haberme dado feedback de la solución! Aprecio mucho que lo hayas echo y me alegra haberte sido de ayuda! Aunque me parece mejor la solución que usa al método `indexOf` ya que te permite ajustar sencillamente qué caracteres no deseas que se generen. :D

Answer (score 0):

Como aporte también les entrego un algoritmo capaz de generar contraseñas de x longitud (8 en adelante).

```
public static String generadorContrasenia(int longitud){
    while (longitud < 8){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Lo sentimos, la contraseña debe tener al 
                                      menos 8 caracteres");
        longitud = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite nuevamente la 
                                                                longitud de su 
                                                                contraseña"));
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    String contrasenia = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++){
        contrasenia += (char) (random.nextInt(94)+33);
    }

    System.out.println(contrasenia);
    return contrasenia;
}
```